# Variable assignment setting other variables

Tags: c#, .net

The actual content of this method isn't important, as the question is specific to the language itself I guess. So here it goes.

Here is my method snippet:

```
private CellValidation.CellValidationResult Validate<B, I>(CellValidation cellToValidate, IList<B> baseListToValidateAgainst, IList<I> importListToValidateAgainst, string invalidMessage, DDSFieldEnum fieldEnum) where I : Entities.DDS.DDSEntityFieldBase where B : Entities.DDS.

    //Remove all dashes and /'s for a more realistic mapping check. We don't want the mapping to fail just because the imports - may be different. Also, create local variables of the list as don't want to modify the actual db. 
    cellToValidate.Value = cellToValidate.Value.Replace("-", " ").Trim().ToLower();

   // IList<B> baseList;
    var baseList = baseListToValidateAgainst;
    baseList.Select(x => { x.Value = x.Value.Replace("-", " ").Trim().ToLower(); return x; }).
...
```

So I clearly set local `baseList` variable to equal the parameter passed in, then I modify the `baseList` variable.

However, this seems to modify the parameter `baseListToValidateAgainst` and not only the local variable `baseList`. Why is that?

Comment: `var baseList = baseListToValidate` copies reference to the same collection, it does not copy the collection itself.

Comment: @Pankaj example does not create a shallow copy, nor does it create a deep copy. It only copies a reference.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you are *not* making a copy of the original list, rather you are assigning the variable `baseList` to be the same reference as `baseListToValidateAgainst`

If you wanted a new copy of the list, try `baseListToValidateAgainst.ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

When you set `baseList` to `baseListToValidateAgainst` you are not making a copy of the original list; you only create a *reference* to the original. Any change you make to `baseList` is done to the `baseListToValidateAgainst` object.

This will make a copy:

```
var baseList = baseListToValidateAgainst.ToList();
```

Moreover, if type `B` is mutable, creating a copy of the list is insufficient: you need to create copies of individual items as well. This step may not be straightforward, because it relies on existence of a method in `B` that gives you a copy. For example, if `Entities.DDS` has a member that makes a copy of the object, you could write this:

```
var baseList = baseListToValidateAgainst.Select(i => (B)i.Copy()).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, I did exactly what you suggest in the first code comment and it didn't work.

Comment: @BenDonnelly This means that you have situation #2, i.e. `I` is mutable, and your code modifies it. You need to make copies of objects from the list.

Comment: What do you mean by creating a copy of the object?

Comment: @BenDonnelly I am assuming that by "it didn't work" you mean that modifications inside your method are visible in the objects of `baseListToValidateAgainst`. This could happen only when `B` is a mutable class. You can fix this by giving `Entities.DDS` a method to "clone" the object (I called it `Copy()` in my second code example).

Comment: Yes I got that, but what I was asking is what the clone method would do, and why? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

> Then I modify the baseList variable

No, you haven't modified it.  You have neither modified the variable (there is no later assignment to it, which is what modifying the *variable* would mean) nor have you modified the list that the variable refers to (you have called no methods of `List` that mutate it, such as `Add` or `Remove`), nor have you mutated any of the objects inside of that list (you defined a query that, *when that query is executed* it will mutate the items in the list that the variable refers to, but you never actually execute that query, so those items are never mutated.

You should avoid side-effect causing queries.  They're confusing.  If you want to perform some action for all of the items in that list, then use a `foreach`, that's the proper tool for that specific task:

```
foreach(var item in baseList)
    item.Value = item.Value.Replace("-", " ").Trim().ToLower();
```

And now you've successfully mutated the items in that list.

Comment: This had no effect, the result is the still the same @Servy